# Prove that there are infinitely many integers that are not of the form $n^3+2m^2$ for integers $m,n$. (Hint: Consider the situation modulo 8).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can I get verification on my proof? Thank you.

Prove that there are infinitely many integers that are not of the form $n^3+2m^2$ for integers $m,n$. (Hint: Consider the situation modulo 8).

We consider the situation modulo $8$:
        \begin{array}{c|c}
          n\downarrow,\; m\rightarrow &  0\quad1\quad2\quad3\quad4\quad5\quad6\quad7\quad mod\;8 \\
          \hline
          0 & 0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          1 & 1\quad3\quad1\quad3\quad1\quad3\quad1\quad3\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          2 & 0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          3 & 3\quad5\quad3\quad5\quad3\quad5\quad3\quad5\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          4 & 0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          5 & 5\quad7\quad5\quad7\quad5\quad7\quad5\quad7\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          6 & 0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad0\quad2\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
          7 & 7\quad1\quad7\quad1\quad7\quad1\quad7\quad1\quad\quad\quad\;\; \\
     \end{array}
        Then we can see that $4$ is missing from the table. This means that all integers of the form $8k+4$ cannot be $n^3+2m^2$ for integers $m,n$. Thus, it is clear that there are infinitely many integers that are not of the form $n^3+2m^2$.

Comment: From the table, you can see that any integer of the form $8k+4$ cannot be $n^3 + 2m^2$ for integer $n, m$.

Comment: It's not clear why you write mod $4$ instead of mod $8$ in the last paragraph. Other than that, your proof looks fine. Note that $6$ is also missing in the table.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you write mod $4$ instead of mod $8$ in the last paragraph. I also don’t understand why you write “without getting $n^3+2m^2$”, since the table shows which residues of  $n^3+2m^2$ you *do* get. Other than that, your proof looks fine. Note that $6$ is also missing in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Without a table, you can instead see that if $n^3+2m^2$ is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$

then $n$ must be even

so $n^3$ is divisible by $8$

so $2m^2$ is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$

so $m^2$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$

which is impossible because if $m$ is even then $4$ divides $m^2$ while if $m$ is odd then $m^2$ is odd.